# Valgrind, "uninitialized value(s)" error

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, initialization, valgrind

In my C program, I'm allocating memory using `malloc()` which does, in contrast to `calloc()`, *not* initialize the memory and it might still contain garbage. Mostly, in context of the allocation, I do not make any changes to the memory allocated by `malloc()`. (For example in a function to initialize a struct that contains a buffer, I do not make changes to the buffer's memory, but later on).

Valgrind gives me a lot of theese errors:

- *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)*
- *Use of uninitialised value of size 4*

I *am sure* to never read from memory that was not initialized in these cases.

Should I ignore them or is it better to initialize the memory on allocation? In case I should ignore them, how can I deactivate this error message in Valgrind?

---

**Example 1**:

```
==4253== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4253==    at 0x408EB8E: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1624)
==4253==    by 0x4093C2E: printf (printf.c:35)
==4253==    by 0x40624D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==4253==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4253==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4253==    by 0x8048938: gk_StreamBufferNode_init (stream.c:101)
==4253==    by 0x8048D0D: gk_Stream_bufferWriteProc (stream.c:252)
==4253==    by 0x8048665: main (main.c:21)
```

*Code*:

```
int gk_StreamBufferNode_init(gk_StreamBufferNode* node, int buffer_size,
                             gk_AllocProc malloc) {
    node->buffer = malloc(buffer_size);     // line 101
    if (node->buffer == NULL) {
        return GKIT_FAILEDALLOC;
    }
    node->next = NULL;
    return GKIT_NOERR;
}
```

---

**Example 2**:

```
==4253== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4253==    at 0x402DA39: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4253==    by 0x8048C6E: gk_Stream_bufferWriteProc (stream.c:230)
==4253==    by 0x8048665: main (main.c:21)
==4253==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==4253==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4253==    by 0x8048CE0: gk_Stream_bufferWriteProc (stream.c:248)
==4253==    by 0x8048665: main (main.c:21)
```

*Code*:

```
    /* ... */
    int available_bytes = binfo->buffer_size - bnode->filled;
    int bytes_to_go = size * count;
    int offset = 0;
    int node_offset = 0;
    gk_StreamBufferNode* new_node;
    void* destination = NULL;
    void* source = NULL;

    while (bytes_to_go > 0) {
        destination = bnode->buffer + bnode->filled + node_offset;
        source = buffer + offset;
        if (available_bytes > bytes_to_go) {
            memcpy(destination, source, bytes_to_go);    // line 230
            bnode->filled += bytes_to_go;
            offset += bytes_to_go;
            node_offset = bytes_to_go;
            bytes_to_go = 0;
        }
        else {
            memcpy(destination, source, available_bytes);
            offset += available_bytes;
            node_offset = 0;
            bytes_to_go -= available_bytes;
            bnode->filled += available_bytes;

            #ifdef DEBUG
                assert(bnode->filled == bnode->buffer_size);
            #endif // DEBUG

            // Allocate a new buffer node.
            new_node = (gk_StreamBufferNode*) malloc(sizeof(gk_StreamBufferNode));    // line 248
            if (new_node == NULL) {
                return GKIT_FAILEDALLOC;
            }
            int success = gk_StreamBufferNode_init(new_node, binfo->buffer_size,
                                                   malloc);
            if (success <= GKIT_ERROR) {
                free(new_node);
                return GKIT_FAILEDALLOC;
            }
            bnode->next = new_node;
            bnode = new_node;
            available_bytes = binfo->buffer_size;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not ignore errors like that. If you post some code, we could help you spot a problem. There's an `if` statement in there somewhere, too, because it says "Conditional jump".

Comment: @Als I've added 2 examples. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases you just allocate memory without initializing it. The easiest way is to use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to zero it out. This *may* be a good strategy for simple cases, e.g if you later use a `buffer` as a string that is to be printed. For more complicated use cases assign values to the individual fields, or even better if you have C99 assign the whole structure from a compound literal:

```
toto * t = malloc(sizeof(*t));    
*t = (toto){ 0 };
```

Comment: 1. How should the assignment work? The compiler does not now the size of the memory-block pointed to by `t`. 2. Isn't this a too large overhead? I'm absolutely sure to not read from memory that was not set.

Comment: @NiklasR, it knows the type of `*t`, so this is an assignment of a value to an object of type `toto`. The only types for which this wouldn't work is an array type, `struct`, integer or floating point types all would be ok. For the read that you state, I am *absolutely* sure that you *do* read the unitialized memory somewhere, when not explicitly then implicitly in `printf` or so. Usually valgrind is reliable in its findings. No this is not a large overhead, compared to read if from RAM, e.g. RAM is several orders of magnitude slower than CPU. In any case, first get it right, then optimize.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should not be expecting uninitialized memory to contain any value, so having conditional jumps dependent on these shows serious problems.

You should either be initializing the memory (to some known value, eg. `0`), or not refer to its contents unless they have been initialized.

Comment: Even if I'm sure I'm never reading from the uninitialized memory?

Comment: Usually when a program reads from uninitialized memory the author is certain that they aren't reading from it.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @NiklasR: You are reading from uninitialized memory. The first case might just be a false positive caused by an optimized `strlen`, probably reading 4 bytes at a time, possibly reading (but ignoring) uninitialized bytes. You can suppress these if you're sure that they are really false positives (see valgrind's `--suppressions` and `--gen-suppressions` options)